# ListView frequently hangs when Sqlite database cursor is updated

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, parallel-processing, cursor

I have one `EditText` which is used for the purpose of taking user input. Once the user enters certain data, the text changing listener associated with the `EditText` calls for a refreshed cursor and tries to update the result which is being displayed in the `ListView`, placed just below.

Everything is fine. But whenever any change in the search query occurs, the resulting cursor and `ListView` update takes some time, say around *n* seconds. During this span of *n* second, the UI stops (halts/hangs whatever you may call) and does not respond until a refreshed cursor is available and the entire `ListView` is populated.

When I tried to put the updating of the cursor in a different thread, it did not allow the same to be reflected in the UI as the UI-thread does not allow being commanded by other threads in action. Any UI activity such as the list update has to be implemented through `runOnUiThread` in the `MainActivity` class.

Kindly suggest ways by which I can allow the EditText to be modified by the user as well as the updated cursor refreshing the ListView happen without affecting the former.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying the wrong approach. When we want the data for the list to be sourced directly from an SQLite database query, we can use a CursorAdapter.

Create an adapter

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    // Default constructor
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        ...
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ...
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        return null;
    }
}

Get Values from database
Cursor todoCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM todo_items", null);
```

Now, we can use the CursorAdapter in the Activity to display an array of items into the ListView:

```
// Find ListView to populate
ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
// Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
// Attach cursor adapter to the ListView 
lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
This will then trigger the CursorAdapter iterating through the result set and populating the list. We can change the cursor to update the adapter at any time with:

// Switch to new cursor and update contents of ListView
todoAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

Comment: I have used a CursorAdaptor and in the bindView method, I have done all that has to be done. But still during the fetching of the result for a given query which returns 400 rows, it takes certain time during which the other UI features are at a hanged state.